# React array not mapping correctly

Tags: arrays, reactjs

The JSON data.js file

```
export const paintData = [
  {
    paint: [
            {
        name: "Weathered Moss N380-3",
        lrv: "LRV:49 R:186 G:187 B:179",
        rgb: "186, 187, 179",
        url: "https://www.behr.com/consumer/ColorDetailView/N380-3",
      },
      {
        name: "Jungle Camouflage N350-4",
        lrv: "LRV:38 R:170 G:167 B:148",
        rgb: "170, 167, 148",
        url: "https://www.behr.com/consumer/ColorDetailView/N350-4/",
      },
    ],
    trim: [
      {
        name: "White 52",
        lrv: "LRV:83 R:235 G:235 B:230",
        rgb: "235, 235, 230",
        url: "https://www.behr.com/consumer/ColorDetailView/52/",
      },
      {
        name: "Authentic Tan N290-2",
        lrv: "LRV:73 R:234 G:221 B:198",
        rgb: "234, 221, 198",
        url: "https://www.behr.com/consumer/ColorDetailView/N290-2/",
      },
    ],
    accent: [
      {
        name: "English Custard M290-5",
        lrv: "LRV:51 R:226 G:182 B:108",
        rgb: "226, 182, 108",
        url: "https://www.behr.com/consumer/ColorDetailView/M290-5/",
      },
      {
        name: "Summerwood S290-4",
        lrv: "LRV:48 R:212 G:178 B:139",
        rgb: "212, 178, 139",
        url: "https://www.behr.com/consumer/ColorDetailView/S290-4/",
      },
    ],
  }
]
```

this is the Paint.js file

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { paintData } from "./data";

export default class Paint extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container className="mb-5">
        <div>
          <p className="font-weight-bold">Approval Exterior Paint Color</p>
          <hr className="my-4" />
          <p className="font-italic">
            What are the approved exterior paint colors?
          </p>
          <p className="text-center lead">
            <strong>
              No Reds, Dark Blue or Soft Boiled P270-6 for base colors.
            </strong>
          </p>
          <p className="text-center">
            Colors may appear different based on your electronic resolution and
            settings. Color codes are the same as retrieved from Behr’s website.
          </p>
          <br />
        </div>
        <Row>
          {paintData.map((data) => {
            return (
              <Col>
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: `rgb(${data.paint.rgb})`,
                    paddintTop: "10px",
                    paddingBottom: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <p>Paint</p>
                  <p>{data.paint.name}</p>
                  <p>{data.paint.lrv}</p>
                  <a href={data.paint.url} target="_blank">
                    Link
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: `rgb(${data.trim.rgb})`,
                    paddintTop: "10px",
                    paddingBottom: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <p>Trim</p>
                  <p>{data.trim.name}</p>
                  <p>{data.trim.lrv}</p>
                  <a href={data.trim.url} target="_blank">
                    Link
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: `rgb(${data.accent.rgb})`,
                    paddintTop: "10px",
                    paddingBottom: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <p>Trim</p>
                  <p>{data.accent.name}</p>
                  <p>{data.accent.lrv}</p>
                  <a href={data.accent.url} target="_blank">
                    Link
                  </a>
                </div>
              </Col>
            );
          })}
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Image:
[image]

I am trying to map three different arrays separately, along with some sub-arrays. The top js file is my JSON file, and the bottom is my Paint.js file. I have an issue mapping out the JSON. How do I map the arrays properly to allow three different categories? The idea is to have 3 paint colors overlap each other for the HOA community. Any help would be great, and thank you in advance.

Comment: completely wrong... You're iterating thought ```paintData``` array, but then ```paint``` it's an array to, and you're accessing him like an ```object``` doing ```data.paint.name```.... you have to map it too to be able to access ```name, lrv, rgb and url```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, would you mind showing me some tutorial or example, please? This is the second React that I have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your replies, I was able to solve the problems in a different route.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Col, Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { paintData } from "../data/paintData";
import { trimData } from "../data/trimData";
import { accentData } from "../data/accentData";

export default class Paint extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container className="mb-5">
        <div>
          <p className="font-weight-bold">Approval Exterior Paint Color</p>
          <hr className="my-4" />
          <p className="font-italic">
            What are the approved exterior paint colors?
          </p>
          <p className="text-center lead">
            <strong>
              No Reds, Dark Blue or Soft Boiled P270-6 for base colors.
            </strong>
          </p>
          <p className="text-center">
            Colors may appear different based on your electronic resolution and
            settings. Color codes are the same as retrieved from Behr’s website.
          </p>
          <br />
        </div>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            {paintData.map((data) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: `rgb(${data.rgb})`,
                    paddingTop: "10px",
                    paddingBottom: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <p>Paint</p>
                  <p>{data.name}</p>
                  <p>{data.lrv}</p>
                  <a href={data.url} target="_blank">
                    Link to {data.name}
                  </a>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </Col>
          <Col>
            {trimData.map((data) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: `rgb(${data.rgb})`,
                    paddingTop: "10px",
                    paddingBottom: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <p>Trim</p>
                  <p>{data.name}</p>
                  <p>{data.lrv}</p>
                  <a href={data.url} target="_blank">
                    Link to {data.name}
                  </a>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </Col>
          <Col>
            {accentData.map((data) => {
              return (
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: `rgb(${data.rgb})`,
                    paddingTop: "10px",
                    paddingBottom: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <p>Accent</p>
                  <p>{data.name}</p>
                  <p>{data.lrv}</p>
                  <a href={data.url} target="_blank">
                    Link to {data.name}
                  </a>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Everyone's posts have given me ideas on how to fix the problem that I have been facing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just taking your paint section

Instead of

```
<div
  style={{
    background: `rgb(${data.paint.rgb})`,
    paddintTop: "10px",
    paddingBottom: "10px",
  }}
>
  <p>Paint</p>
  <p>{data.paint.name}</p>
  <p>{data.paint.lrv}</p>
  <a href={data.paint.url} target="_blank">
    Link
  </a>
</div>
```

Try this( I didn't test this code, but should work)

```
{data.paint.map((paintItem)=> {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          background: `rgb(${paintItem.rgb})`,
          paddintTop: "10px",
          paddingBottom: "10px",
        }}
      >
      <p>Paint</p>
          <p>{paintItem.name}</p>
          <p>{paintItem.lrv}</p>
          <a href={paintItem.url} target="_blank">
            Link
          </a>
        </div>
    )
  })
}
```

You were not seeing the data because this code `<p{data.paint.name}</p>` is actually trying to access `data.paint` which is an array.

*You will need to update the other sections as well, where you use trim and accent*

Also Tip: would be easier to read and manage if you separate this code into diff components.

Comment: Thank you! Your "Tip" gave me a good idea! :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can only iterate over arrays, not objects.

This must be iteration part you are looking for.

```
{
    paintData.paint.map( (paint, index) => (
        <Col>
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: `rgb(${paint.rgb})`,
                    paddintTop: "10px",
                    paddingBottom: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <p>Paint</p>
                  <p>{paint.name}</p>
                  <p>{paint.lrv}</p>
                  <a href={paint.url} target="_blank">
                    Link
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: `rgb(${paintData.trim[index].rgb})`,
                    paddintTop: "10px",
                    paddingBottom: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <p>Trim</p>
                  <p>{paintData.trim[index].name}</p>
                  <p>{paintData.trim[index].lrv}</p>
                  <a href={paintData.trim[index].url} target="_blank">
                    Link
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div
                  style={{
                    background: `rgb(${paintData.accent[index].rgb})`,
                    paddintTop: "10px",
                    paddingBottom: "10px",
                  }}
                >
                  <p>Trim</p>
                  <p>{paintData.accent[index].name}</p>
                  <p>{paintData.accent[index].lrv}</p>
                  <a href={paintData.accent[index].url} target="_blank">
                    Link
                  </a>
                </div>
              </Col>
    ))
}
```